# Top personal income tax deductibles in Germany?

Tags: taxes, germany, business

Just moved to and started working as a freelancer in Germany and was wondering what things/deductibles are the best way to rescue some money from the taxman at the end of the year?

I'm a graphic designer and unfortunately have almost 0 expenses throuhout the year - will not need new hardware or software, don't have a car and work remotely most of the time (few travel expenses). It seems I'm doomed to pay a lot of tax - or how do you guys save money on that? What would be the "biggest" deductibles?

Comment: I think this question would be more suted on a Q&A site specializing in tax issues and startups/freelancers

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, in case you don't have any business related expenses you can't claim anything there. You can be able to claim part of your apartment rent if you register one or more rooms as home office. Also, you may be able to claim your internet and phone bills, in case you can prove that you used them only for work, but that's about it.